# Send FormData to controller via ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, multipartform-data

I want to upload form in asp.net mvc. This is my form

```
<form id="fm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="no" id="txteno" data-bind="value: $root.PersonId" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="text" name="name" id="txtename" data-bind="value: $root.PersonName" />
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" data-bind="file: {data: Photo, name: PersonPhoto, reader: someReader} " />
<button data-bind="click :$root.save" >Save</button>
</form>
```

I use Form Data to upload this form. This is my view model

```
var ViewModel = function () {
//declare observable
var perData = {
//evaluate object
};
var PerData = new FormData();
self.save = function () {
//append data 
PerData.append('no',perData.PersonId()); PerData.append('name',perData.PersonName());
PerData.append('file', perData.Photo());
PerData.append('file', perData.PersonPhoto());
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/Person/FileUpload",
data: PerData,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
cache: false,
//mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
success: function () {
alert("Record Added Successfully");
},
error: function () {
alert("fail");}
});};};
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

and this is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(Person item,HttpPostedFileBase file)
 { //some code}
```

sending form via ajax is successful but item and file pass to my controller,  are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider moving the "click:" binding on the button to a "submit:" binding on the form.

This will allow you to use the form data like so:

```
this.submit = function(form) {
  var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);

  return false;
}
```

If you can provide a sample JSFiddle, I may be able to get you some working code.

Here is my example fiddle to show a proof of concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/bryanray/h5osqq17/

Also, keep in mind that the name of the fields on the ajax POST need to match up directly to the Controllers parameters in order for the .NET Model Binding to hook up correctly. This is convention based.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to pass the `form` in the `.FormData(form)`:

```
var PerData = new FormData($('#fm')[0]); // pass the form here.
self.save = function () {
   // use ajax as is but remove the append to form data.
};
```

Comment: Okay! `perData.Photo()` does it return anything in your code?

Comment: PerData is filled in view model but ajax sends null to FileUpload action